# createTcpServer: address already in use Error in initialize(...) : Failed to create server

Tags: r, tcpserver, blastula, microsoft365r

**I'm writing scripts in R.**

Please do not remove my question as I checked and this is certainly (and unfortunately) one of a kind.

I'm a newbie data analyst and I was trifling around with learning how to send emails, and I tried using the blastula package and I was playing around with credentials or something.

Instead, I ended up messing something up and I really need help.
Please do not tell me to "re-authenticate" as that is very, very unhelpful because I barely know what I'm doing and this error I am getting is a result of my TRYING to authenticate.

ChatGPT said a "port is blocked". It's been "blocked" for 2 days now.
I can't find which port is blocked to clear it.

I am trying to "read" into my inbox through Microsoft365R.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
>   outlb <- get_business_outlook()
Using authorization_code flow
Creating Microsoft Graph login for default tenant
Using authorization_code flow
createTcpServer: address already in use
Error in initialize(...) : Failed to create server
```

How do I fix this?

I am going to re-install the Microsoft365R package and try again and I will update if that works.

Until then...
Please. Help. Me.

---

TL;DR

Error:

```
>   outlb <- get_business_outlook()
Using authorization_code flow
Creating Microsoft Graph login for default tenant
Using authorization_code flow
createTcpServer: address already in use
Error in initialize(...) : Failed to create server
```

Update: I tried reinstalling Microsoft365R. No dice.

Comment: `get_business_outlook` doesn't seem to be from `blastula`, according to the docs. https://pkgs.rstudio.com/blastula/reference/index.html

Comment: I stopped using blastula because it decided to block my ports.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution and I'll leave it here in case somebody runs into the same issue.
Once the server restarted, I was able to reauthenticate and the error was gone.

Comment: What's the solution? I don't see it and am having the exact same issue.

Comment: Our server restarted over the weekend, I reauthenticated and the error went away. Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: ah ok, no I am no longer having the issue. I had to reauthenticate as well, but the window that was asking me to do so was always hidden so I never saw it.